# What is the time complexity of JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, time-complexity

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26708363/771665) answer, the time complexity of `JSON.parse()` is `O(n)`.

Does this hold true for `JSON.stringify()`? There does not appear to be anywhere that documents this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the complexity of JSON.parse() in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708229/what-is-the-complexity-of-json-parse-in-javascript)

Comment: Depends on what `n` is, but I would think that it'd be pretty linear as well

Comment: It's considered `O(n)` as simple grammar doesn't require even lookaheads. < Right from the post.

Comment: @Alex he already linked to that question. It's about parsing, his question is about stringify.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Are you suggesting that the time complexity changes for large n? Why would that be?

Comment: Oh, I get it, you mean it depends on how you calculate `n` from the input value.

Comment: @Barmar No, I was just wondering what OP (or anyone) would consider `n` to measure. Recursive sum of total values (or key-value pairs), maybe

Comment: Just always remember, that apart of the "time complexity of `JSON.stringify`", you also have to consider evaluating properties may actually be slow: `const x = { get bad() { let now = +new Date(); while (+new Date() - now < 5000); return "FINISHED" } }; JSON.stringify(x);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be O(n), but `n` is the number of nodes in the entire object hierarchy of the value being stringified. So if you have an array of numbers, `n` is `array.length`. But if you have an object like:

```
var obj = 
    { a: [1, 2, 3],
      b: { x: 1, y: z },
      c: { q: [1, 2], r: "abc" }
    }
```

`n` is 3 (properties of `obj`) + 3 (elements of `obj.a`) + 2 (elements of `obj.b`) + 2 (elements of `obj.c`) + 2 (elements of `obj.c.q`) = 12

This also treats stringifying strings as constant, but in actuality they're O(n) where n` is the length of the string. But unless you have lots of long strings in the object, the difference is probably not significant.

Comment: If I do, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)), then it will be O(N^2) right?

Comment: No, it's stll O(n). It's two consecutive O(n) operations, not nested.

Comment: Can you explain intuition behind it? I cant understand why it will be still O(n)? Because .parse() and .stringify() both are O(n) separately, then it should be O(nxn). For each string converted by .stringify() will be parsed right?

Comment: Why would you multiply? If you have two consecutive loops that each do N operations, they do N+N=2N operations when combined, not N*N operations. Since you discard coefficients when doing big-O calculations, O(2N) is the same as O(N).